# IIS mystery: "Deadlock detected" periodically makes site unavailable

Tags: iis-6, asp.net, debugging, vb.net, deadlock

A few times a day, our vb.net (IIS 6.0) website is randomly throwing the following error and becomes completely unavailable for 5-15 minutes at a time while the application is recycled:

ISAPI 'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll' reported itself as unhealthy for the following reason: 'Deadlock detected'.

The website ran for months on the exact same server in beta without problem - but the problem started over the weekend when we made the site live.  The live site is under some load but less than many of our other production websites.

How should I attack this problem?  I've looked into orphaning the worker process and creating a dump file - but I'm not sure how to analyze that.  Any advice or information is appreciated.  Thanks,
Shane

Comment: Refer to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821268 if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good article on starting with analyzing dumps [Hang caused by GC - XML Deadlock](https://web.archive.org/web/20150628230803/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/tess/archive/2008/02/11/hang-caused-by-gc-xml-deadlock.aspx). You can also look for some examples [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/search/SearchResults.aspx?q=asp.net+deadlock)

Comment: +1 for any articles that link to Tess Ferrandez :) The goddess of debugging!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest upgrading the OS to 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5